# How do you manage users on shared always-on PCs that can run long processes and need to have GUI always on?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, active-directory

We use Microsoft Active Directory for authentication and user group management, and it works great for "normal" office work.

In certain manufacturing scenarios you can run a PCs with a software that needs to be always-on, and one person can start a process and go home, another person come in and monitor the process to completion. How can this be managed without shared log-in accounts?

if this is on Windows 10 or 11, is it still not possible or advisable to run any program on top of Lock Screen?

Answer (score 0):

Programs cannot run "on top" of the login screen.

Absent a shared login you're limited to the software supporting this. It would require a service/client setup, I suppose, where the service is handling the ongoing processing, and the client programs running in the user sessions would be able to be signed out/signed in without impacting the processing.

I'm no Windows Dev, but I've supported Windows environments for decades. From what I understand applications run as the user they are initiated as, so if you require the ongoing processing the application must be able to run some part of itself outside the user session, and this means a service for on-system running, or a client/server setup.